# String non callable in python 3

Tags: string, python-3.x

I've met a strange problem while doing the 16th exercice of Learn Python the Hard Way (2nd edition, LPTHW).
I have first typed the code, the copied it, and when I execute the script on my console (with python ex16.py test.txt), the same message appears:

```
File "ex16.py", line 19, in <module>  
line1 = input("line 1: ")  
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

The code is:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print("We're going to erase %r." % filename)
print("If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).")
print("If you do want that, hit RETURN.")

input = ("?")

print("Opening the file...")
target = open(filename, 'w')

print("Truncating the file. Goodbye!")
target.truncate()

print("Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.")

line1 = input("line 1: ")
line2 = input("line 2: ")
line3 = input("line 3: ")

print("I'm going to write these to the file.")

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print("And finally, we close it.")
target.close()
```

Is this caused by the fact that LPTHW is made for Python 2.7 and I use Python 3.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shadowed the builtin `input` function right here:

```
input = ("?")
```

The equal sign assigns to a variable named `input`, which shadows the built-in `input()` function. Remove the equal sign and your code will work:

```
input("?")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My mistake comes from the = sign, which shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = ("?")
```

comment out the above and retry the script.